# URL variables and PHP redirects, can they be cached?

Tags: php, caching, browser-cache, urlvariables

Two questions rolled into one.

Can browsers in general cache a URL (js  script) if it's requested with URL variables?
E.g. www.thing.com/?l=lib&s=thing.js

Can browsers cache a file if it is a php redirect?
E.g. www.thing.com/script.js (called, is a php file with a redirect to www.thing2.com/actual.js)

Thanks.

Comment: A browser will generally cache any URL it's allowed (via cache policy headers, though a browser can still choose to ignore those), basically any request result may potentially be cacheable. However note that : `www.thing.com/?l=lib&s=thing.js` and `www.thing.com/?s=thing.js&l=lib` could be different in the eyes of the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have two questions

1. Can browsers in general cache a URL (js script) if it's requested with URL variables? E.g. www.thing.com/?l=lib&s=thing.js

   Yes.
2. Can browsers cache a file if it is a php redirect? E.g. www.thing.com/script.js (called, is a php file with a redirect to www.thing2.com/actual.js)

   Depends. If the redirect is a 301, then yes [per the spec](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.2)

   > The requested resource has been assigned a new permanent URI and any future references to this resource SHOULD use one of the returned URIs. Clients with link editing capabilities ought to automatically re-link references to the Request-URI to one or more of the new references returned by the server, where possible. **This response is cacheable unless indicated otherwise.**

   If the redirect is a 302, then [maybe](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.3)

   > The requested resource resides temporarily under a different URI. Since the redirection might be altered on occasion, the client SHOULD continue to use the Request-URI for future requests. **This response is only cacheable if indicated by a Cache-Control or Expires header field.**

Comment: Thank you. My current setup uses 302 and seems to never cache stuff. I'll change them over too 301.